# How proof the Lorentz algebra using the Poincaré algebra?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lie-algebra, lorentz-symmetry, poincare-symmetry

> Show that
>   $$[J_{i},J_{j}]=i\varepsilon_{ijk}J_{k},\quad [K_{i},K_{j}]=-i\varepsilon_{ijk}J_{k}, \quad [J_{i},K_{j}]=i\varepsilon_{ijk}K_{j},$$ 
>   using $$[M_{\mu\nu},M_{\rho\sigma}]=ig_{\nu\rho}M_{\mu\sigma}+ig_{\mu\sigma}M_{\nu\rho}-ig_{\mu\rho}M_{\nu\sigma}-ig_{\nu\sigma}M_{\mu\rho}. $$
>   Hint: $M_{\mu\nu}=-M_{\nu\mu}$, $M_{0i}=K_{i}$ and $M_{ij}=\varepsilon_{ijk}J_{k}$.

This doubt is in the page 4 of following reference: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0101055

Answer (score 2):

Just to take one term: letting $\mu = \rho = 0$ and $\nu = i \in \{1,2,3\},\;\sigma = j \in \{1,2,3\}$ we can immediately write$$[M_{0i},M_{0j}] = [K_i, K_j] = i g_{i0} M_{0j} + i g_{0j} M_{i0} - i g_{00} M_{ij} - i g_{ij} M_{00}.$$
Antisymmetry means $M_{00} = 0$ and the fact that $g$ is diagonal [more specifically, $g = \operatorname{diag}(1, -1, -1, -1)$ as far as I can tell] means that $g_{0j} = g_{i0} = 0$ as these are off-diagonal terms. That leaves just $g_{00} = 1$ and $M_{ij} = \epsilon_{ijk} J_k,$ proving:$$[K_i, K_j] = -i \epsilon_{ijk} J_k.$$Other terms are left as an exercise for you.